# EarlyStopping using epoch level metrics in Pytorch Lightning

Tags: python, tensorboard, pytorch-lightning

I have written a classifier in pytorch lightning, and I'd like to plot training/validation loss and accuracy against the epoch number, rather than the step number, which seems to be the default behaviour. I can do this using the following code (using tensorboard as the logger:

```
def validation_epoch_end(self, outputs):
    val_loss = torch.stack([x['loss'] for x in outputs]).mean()
    val_acc = torch.stack([x['accuracy'] for x in outputs]).mean()
    self.logger.experiment.add_scalar(
        "Loss/Validation",
        val_loss,
        self.current_epoch)
    self.logger.experiment.add_scalar(
        "Accuracy/Validation",
        val_acc,
        self.current_epoch)
```

I'd now like to use the metric `Accuracy/Validation` in the `EarlyStopping` callback:

```
trainer = pl.Trainer(
    default_root_dir=root_dir,
    callbacks=[EarlyStopping(monitor='Accuracy/Validation', mode='max', patience=5)],
    max_epochs=100,
    logger=tb_logger
)
```

This doesn't work, as it can't find `Accuracy/Validation`. The only way I've been able to work around this is also call `self.log` in the validation step:

```
def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
    loss, acc = self.forward(batch, mode='val')
    self.log(
        "val_loss",
        loss,
        on_step=False,
        on_epoch=True,
    )
    self.log(
       "val_accuracy",
        acc,
        on_step=False,
        on_epoch=True,
    )
    return {'loss': loss, "accuracy": acc}
```

I can now use `val_accuracy` in the `EarlyStopping` callback, however this now duplicates the plot I want but with the step number on the x-axis. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to log several values you should use `log_dict` instead of `log`. Like this:

```py
metrics = {
    'val_loss': loss,
    'val_accuracy': acc
}
    
self.log_dict(metrics, on_step=False, on_epoch=True)
```